# Is there a way to trigger an automatic import of a WP backup on creation of a new WP multisite site?

Tags: content, multisite, import

I have a WP backup file of sample content I use when I set up a new site on my WP multisite install (I use it for theme dev work for clients).  Is there a way to trigger the import function to fire when I create a new site?  I've looked at the WPMU blog defaults plugin, but there are features it doesn't have that I would like (such as post tags and child/parent categories).

A little more detail...

Settings > Import (actually Tools > Import, since it moved from the Settings menu a release or two ago) is what I'm looking to automate.  As I mentioned, I have a WXR file of content I normally import manually whenever I create a new site.  I would like to remove that manual step from my workflow.  The backup file itself is stored on my dev server, so WP would have direct access to it.

Comment: Where are you envisioning this sample content would be located to be automatically imported? I assume you are doing something more complex than just a "Settings > Import?"

Comment: I added a bit more detail to my original question to try to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-dummy-content/stats/

It is random content so if you need to always to load the same content you will have to look at the code and create your own version.

> One pain of theme development is
>   setting up all the pages and blog
>   posts in order for you to see how your
>   site will look � one by one by one.
>
> No more!
>
> WP-Dummy-Content is a WordPress plugin
>   that will generate a bunch of pages,
>   sub-pages and posts which you specify.
>   Titles and content are automatically
>   generated for you as well, and you
>   have a few choices as to the type and
>   length of content.
>
> One click generates an entire site.
>   Choose what type of content to insert:
>   single paragraph, multi paragraphs,
>   styled (lists, blockquotes, links,
>   etc.), or random. One click DELETES
>   all content created by the plugin!

Comment: Hmmm...that might work.  I'll have to do some digging to see if there's a way to get it to add, at the very least, categories but it's a start...

Comment: it will create all the categories and user as needed the importer is a good tool

Comment: the importer will create missing categories and users it works quite well