# Some way to Flush or Overwrite all Imported Content in a Site for a Fresh Import - How?

Tags: plugins, content, import, scripts, customization

Some way to Flush or Overwrite all Imported Content in a Site for a Fresh Import - How?

- Is there an easy quick way to do this? To delete all Pages, Posts, Comments and stuff that got imported?
- Or some way to force a FLUSH of the information when I import a new .XML?
- I've imported a bunch of wrong content into several sites
- I would like to give them a FRESH start, preferably without having to Re-Create Fresh Sites on Multisite WP 3.5.1 Network
- Make it go back to the state when a Fresh New Site was created

With relation to other links I've read:

- [Import and replace existing page/post content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14779/import-and-replace-existing-page-post-content)
- [Can I overwrite existing posts with Import tool?](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-i-overwrite-existing-posts-with-import-tool)
- [How do I re-import overwriting all posts/comments?](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-re-import-overwriting-all-postscomments)
- [Wordpress Import Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036233/wordpress-import-function)
- [Import and replace existing page/post content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14779/import-and-replace-existing-page-post-content)
- [Is there a way to trigger an automatic import of a WP backup on creation of a new WP multisite site?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-an-automatic-import-of-a-wp-backup-on-creation-of-a-ne?rq=1)

I haven't gotten a conclusive answer here. Not even when I put together all the LEARNING from the links I've read (posted).

**Is there a way to combine all the above knowledge to create solution steps for this?**

**Shouldn't there be a Plugin, Script or some Tool in the Wordpress Admin/ Developer's Tool chest to do this sometime when needed?**

**Is there something like this out there?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/suicide/.
As a super admin you can select which sites you would like to remove the content from within your multisite setup.

Comment: nice name; Suicide!

Comment: Also, this looks like a "link-only answer". Should it not be a comment instead? Or is "self-contained" not a criteria for this SE site? Actual question - on StackOverflow, this would be considered a comment, not an answer,, and be subject to deletion, but I dunno if the criteria is different here.

Comment: The plugin is outdated (last updated 7 years ago): tested up to WP version 3.9.33, but current WP version is 5.6.

Answer (score 1):

**Run A Query to Delete All posts before Import**

Because menus and pages are custom post types, this will update all posts, pages, and menus to be replaced by your import file.

1. Delete all posts in the target server by running a database query. Note that the code requires setting a userid. modify it if there are more users or run it more than once.

```
SET @WPUSERID='1';
-- end config

--       DELETE a , b , c FROM wp_posts a
--         LEFT JOIN
--     wp_term_relationships b ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
--         LEFT JOIN
--     wp_postmeta c ON (a.ID = c.post_id) 
-- WHERE
--     a.post_author = @WPUSERID;
```

(uncomment lines after the `--end config`, by deleting the leading `--`  In order to run the query. But be careful, it is destructive.  See the query below on how test your query to see what will be deleted, before you run it.)

2. Import the XML file to the target.

> **Caution**: Back up your databases for both servers in case you accidently get them mixed up (you think you're connected to stage for example, and you are really connected to dev when you do the delete) .

**Be safe: view posts before deleting**

```
SET @WPUSERID='1';
-- end config

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    wp_posts a
        LEFT JOIN
    wp_term_relationships b ON (a.ID = b.object_id)
        LEFT JOIN
    wp_postmeta c ON (a.ID = c.post_id)
WHERE
    a.post_author = @WPUSERID;
```